# vertical align headache

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Im having trouble vertical aligning 2 divs inside a 100% height div. I googled but failed solving.

pseudocode:

```
<div container, fixed height>
  <img, dynamic height/>
  <div inner, 100% height>
    <div><img/></div>
    <div><img/></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The two divs in the inner div, i want them to be in the vertical center of the inner div, but i cant find a way. its not possible to know the height of the inner div, its just set to 100% because of the random height of the image above it. The divs inside the inner div will also have dynamic heights.

2 hours of fiddling around gave no results, so im coming here.

The page where you can see it in action: http://pyntmeg.no/?iframe

Comment: In what context are you displaying these elements? I'm just curious, because there may be another way to do this than trying to get them to align in the center, which is very hard with CSS.

Comment: what other way is that? i dont need to have the code like this, no. this whole thing is meant to be displayed inside an iframe as an ad.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to understand. Does it HAVE to be aligned vertically in the center? That's what I want to know. There may be other options for displaying the code that we haven't thought of. What is the average height/width of the ads, what is the average height/width of the element the ad will be in?

Comment: it will be in an iframe fixed at `height:395px; width:175px;`. if i place the divs in the inner div always on top, then when it comes two images with a low height, the ad will have alot of white space in the bottom and it doesnt look good.

Comment: well, if i were you, to save some headaches, I would always require that the ads are a fixed size. That's a pretty common thing in the banner ad world anyway. I know it doesn't fix your problem, but that's probably the only solution.

Comment: i cant require it as its my own webshops, and the images are a dynamic height, i cannot change it ;) oh well thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

You can give the parent DIV.container a position :relative property since it has a fixed height.

The inner div can then have a position:absolute and you set its height to 100% or maybe a little lower. you can use the top property to move it around.

Comment: the divs inside the inner div will also have dynamic heights :/

Comment: That shouldnt be a problem because your parent div has a fixed height. you can even add an overflow property for scrolling if necessary

Comment: i changed my code on the site now, but the divs are not being vertically centered, maybe i did it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.item {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
}
```

You may need to adjust top: 10%;

Comment: i tried it, seems to be the closest one, but its not right still. seems to be working for some images but not others.

Comment: That's probably because the images are different heights. This won't achieve the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the parent/grandparent divs have the width to work with it you can apply 'float: left' to the grandchild divs style.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` is meant for table elements, not regular divs, etc. In order to get `vertical-align` middle to work, the element needs to be set to `display:table-cell` and it's parent needs to be set to `display:table-row`

Be careful with that, though, because it really does change the way the element interacts with it's sibling elements, and it could definitely change how your page is laid out.

The best use of this would be something like this:

```
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="td">lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="td">dolor sit amat</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.table-row {display: table-row}
.td {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
```

**NOTE**

This will not work with elements that are floated left/right, and it will change how the border width effects the overall width of the element.

I would only use this with tabular data, much like I would suggest only using a table.